# Getting the "name" of a named destination with Poppler

Tags: c, pdf, poppler

I have a PDF document that I'd like to show the named destinations for. I'm using Poppler to do so. What I need is a list of the named destination in the document, including the names and the locations. For now, I am considering only `XYZ` destinations.

Let's use the [LaTeX hyperbar manual](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperbar/hyperbar.pdf) as an example PDF. From `pdfinfo -dests hyperbar.pdf`, we can see there are some `XYZ` named destinations in this document:

```
Page  Destination                 Name
   1 [ XYZ  145  716 null      ] "Doc-Start"
   1 [ XYZ   71  502 null      ] "HD.1"
   1 [ XYZ  144  754 null      ] "page.1"
   ....
```

Let's take `HD.1` as an example. This named destination can be looked up from the `PopplerDocument` as expected, including the position. However, the `named_dest` field is `NULL`:

```c
PopplerDoc* poppler_doc = poppler_document_new_from_file("hyperbar.pdf", NULL, NULL);

PopplerDest* dest = poppler_document_find_dest (poppler_doc, "HD.1");

printf("pos:  p %d L %f T %f\n", dest->page_num, dest->left, dest->top);
printf("name: %s\n", dest->named_dest);
```

produces:

```
pos:  p 1 L 71.004000 T 502.496000
name: (null)
```

According to the [Poppler documentation](https://people.freedesktop.org/~ajohnson/docs/poppler-glib/PopplerAction.html#PopplerDest-struct), the `PopplerDest.named_dest` field is only set when the destination is a `POPPLER_DEST_NAMED`, which this is not.

Iterating all the destinations in the document returned via `poppler_document_create_dests_tree()` is the same - `named_dest` is always NULL.

So, my question is: considering that `pdfinfo` is able to report the names of the destinations, even for `XYZ` destinations, can I get these names from a PDF file using Poppler?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all pages of a document, extract link objects and there you can obtain named destinations.

```
GError *err = NULL;
PopplerDocument *doc = poppler_document_new_from_file("<uri to your file>",
                                                      NULL,
                                                      &err);
if(!doc){
    g_print("Failed to load document.\ndomain: %d, \ncode: %d, \nmessage: %s\n",
            err->domain, err->code, err->message);
    return;
}
int num_pages = poppler_document_get_n_pages(doc);
for(int page_num = 0; page_num < num_pages; page_num++){
    PopplerPage *page = poppler_document_get_page(doc,
                                                  page_num);

    GList *link_mappings = poppler_page_get_link_mapping(page);
    GList *link_p = link_mappings;
    while(link_p){
        PopplerLinkMapping *link_mapping = link_p->data;
        switch(link_mapping->action->type){
            case POPPLER_ACTION_GOTO_DEST:
            {
                PopplerActionGotoDest *goto_dest_action = (PopplerActionGotoDest*)
                    link_mapping->action;
                if(goto_dest_action->dest->type == POPPLER_DEST_NAMED){
                    g_print("Page: '%d', named_dest: '%s'\n",
                            page_num, dest->named_dest);
                } 
                break;
            }
            default:;
        }
        link_p = link_p->next;
    }
    poppler_page_free_link_mapping(link_mappings);
    g_object_unref(page);
}
g_object_unref(doc);
```